# How should I fit the sample data in model combining CNN and LSTM

Tags: keras

I have a sample data of page visits of one page for 803 days. I have extracted features from data like mean, median etc and final shape of data is (803, 25). I had taken a train set of 640 and a test set of 160. I am trying to use CNN+LSTM model using Keras. But I am getting an error in model.fit method.

I have tried permute layer and changed input shapes but still not able to fix it.

```
trainX.shape = (642, 1, 25)
trainY.shape = (642,)
testX.shape = (161, 1, 25) 
testY.shape = (161,)
'''python

# Basic layer

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), strides=1, padding='SAME', input_shape = (642, 25, 1), activation = 'relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Permute((2, 3), input_shape=(1, 25)))
model.add(LSTM(units=54, return_sequences=True))

# To avoid overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.2))  

# Adding 6 more layers
model.add(LSTM(units=25, return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))  
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=54))
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units = 1, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.0001))))

model.add(PReLU(weights=None, alpha_initializer="zero"))   # add an advanced activation

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = customSmapeLoss, metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 50,  batch_size = 32)

predictions = model.predict(testX)  

'''


#Runtime Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-218-86932db86d0b> in <module>()
     42 
     43 model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = customSmapeLoss, metrics=['mae'])
---> 44 model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 50,  batch_size = 32)


Error - IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The input_shape requires a tuple of length 4 when it using TimeDistributed with Conv2D

see https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/

```
input_shape=(10, 299, 299, 3))
```

Dont you think your data field is too little? usually, CNN+LSTM is meant for a more complicated task with thousands of sequential images/videos.

Comment: Actually, the data field will increase once I leverage the model for more pages around 1 lakh. Currently, I am trying only for a single page to understand the model

Comment: tuple of length 4 have to tried this? is it the reason or index error?

Comment: I have used tuple  of dimension 4. Still I am getting same error. Here is my input shape now - (10,642, 25, 1)